# Bakckground gets drawn over Buttons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have GUI(JFrame) with some Buttons. I also juse the paint(Graphics G) methode to draw a shape (for the game I am woarking on).

I want to draw a background so I put that first in the paint methode:

```
 public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(img,0,20,null);
    
    //167,230      288,409
    g2.dispose();
    }
```

But the Image gets drawn over the Buttons but not over the first(the on with the lower X coordinate) and when I hover over the place where the other Buttons are placed then they get Drawn too but till then they are "Invisibil".

How can I draw the Image really as Bakckground so it dosend get Painted over other Objeckts?

First I tryed put the Buttons on `FocusPainted = true` but that doesend worked.

Then I tryed to draw the Image only the first Time the paint Component gets Called so it only overlays the Buttons at first loading but then stays behind them.

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    
    tower1.draw(g2);
    tower2.draw(g2);
    tower3.draw(g2);
    
    if (firstPaint == false) {
      g2.drawImage(img,0,0,null);
      firstPaint = true;
    } // end of if
    
    
    g2.dispose();
    }
```

But when the it gets repainted the Image disappers....

Then I tryed use the JFrame own Graphis :
`this.getContentPane().getGraphics().drawImage(img,0,0,null);`
then the the GUI dosend even load.

Comment: Why override paint and then call super.paintComponents and not super.paint?

Comment: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a solution.
There is a methode `UpdateUI` which I can call after drawing the image.
This makes the JPannel drawn them after the Image.

THX alot for your help with you coments I found out a lot more then I needed which will help me on my journy!

Comment: updateUI is __wrong__! please read the api doc to understand what it is meant for (in short: it's for updated when the component's ui delegate is changed) Instead of random method invoking, learn how to do custom painting correctly

Comment: What woud be the right way to go if updateUi is wrong?
Coud you give me some hints or videos which help me lern?

Comment: do the custom painting correctly - see the referenced tutorial

Comment: One of the comments gave you a good hint. You're overriding `paint` then you're calling `super.paintComponent` Override paintComponent. instead of paint. When you override paint, you're removing a lot of paint code. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html